# Excel highlight the next row with a blank cell in a specific range

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I am trying to highlight the next row in a range that contains a blank cell. I have tried using various formula rules for conditional formatting, but I've not had any success.

Some of the formula I have tried are:

```
=COUNTIF($A5:$H:34)

=ISBLANK($A5:$H:34)
```

I believe one of the issues is that even though the cells themselves are empty, they are referenced in other cells. When I have managed to get it working to a degree it has only highlighted the empty cells, not the rows just the cells, or it has highlighted everything regardless of whether the row contains a blank cell or not.

Running `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A7:$G7=0))>0` on rows without blanks gives `FALSE`, and gives `TRUE` when run on rows that contain a blank.

**EDIT**

I managed to get it to highlight the correct rows using

```
=COUNTBLANK($A$5:$G35)
```

The next step will be trying to limit the highlighted row to just the first row with a blank cell, not all rows with blank cells.

Comment: Some sample data and the expected output would be really helpful here.

Comment: You would need to make sure the rule applies to the correct range ie: `$A$5:$H$34` then refer to the one row below the upper left cell in that range: `=A6=""`  Conditional formatting will then iterate properly the formula.

Comment: Or if you want to test the full row for any blanks: `=SUMPROUCT(--($A6:$H6<>""))>0`

Comment: Using ```=SUMPRODUCT(--($A7:$H7<>""))>0``` on a row with an empty cell gives me an "divide by zero error".

Comment: That should have worked, but I did have a typo, it should be equal: `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A7:$H7=""))>0` and I get no error on either.

Comment: I only get the error when I run it on a row that has a blank. If I run it on a row with no blanks I get "TRUE". I fixed the error, it was an issue with one of the formulas in a cell. Now I get true no matter where I put it

Comment: I think your formula works, using it on a blank area of the spreadsheet returns "FALSE". I would assume this has something to do with why my blank cells aren't formatting as expected

Comment: are the formulas in the data returning `""` or `" "` it matters.

Comment: the formulas that are referencing the blank cells are simple things like ```=C7-B7``` where C7 is the blank cell and B7 is a cell with values. The blank cells are truly blank as far as I can tell. If I select them there is nothing there, no spaces or anything

Comment: Then how are they blank?

Comment: So as an example B7 has 210 in it, C7 is blank, and D7 contains the formula ```=C7-B7```

Comment: Then I am confused what you want to check.  You need to add a lot more information in you question.  Please [edit] the question with more clarity and test data.

Comment: Using your new formula I get "FALSE" when using it on a row without Blanks, and "TRUE" when used on a row With blanks.

Comment: Using ```=SUMPRODUCT(--($A7:$G7=0))>0``` gives the correct 'TRUE' AND 'FALSE' responses when used on rows with or without blanks, which means the blank cells are truly blank correct?

Comment: Select `A5:H34`. If you meant each row that has a blank cell or contains nothing (`=""`), use `=COUNTBLANK($A5:$H5)>0`. You could use `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISBLANK($A5:$H5))>0` for just blank cells.

Comment: What is wrong with highlighting just the blank cells in the range and leaving to the user to scroll down to find them (or better have  a button to move to next blank in range)?